# What is ""s in this code, and what it basically do?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Wanted to know what does `s = ""s` does in the following code and how is it used!

> ```
> generate(begin(v), end(v), [s = ""s, c = '`']() mutable { ++c; s += c; return s; });
> ```

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;


void use_generate_abc() {
  vector<string> v(5);
  generate(begin(v), end(v), [s = ""s, c = '`']() mutable { ++c; s += c; return s; });
  for(auto x: v)cout << x << " ";
}

int main(){
   std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
   std::cin.tie(NULL);
   use_generate_abc();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, please [don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I literally am tired of advising people that. They simply don't listen :(

Comment: And not to mention usage of `using namespace std`

Comment: And that `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` isn't really needed. It's just something that's for some inexplicably reason happens to be popular on online "competition" sites. Sites which too many people use to learn how to program. And all they will learn is to program for such sites and nothing else. If you really want to learn C++ and programming, get [a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and take a couple of classes.

Comment: guess he is coming from leetcode/hackerrank :)

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 even if the person does not care about `bits/stdc++.h` it is still good to mention it for any other reader. Comments are not only for the OP but for anyone finding that question.

Comment: bits/stdc++.h was included so that the main focus of the question remain on the use_generate_abc function rather than the libraries included! Btw thanks for the the answer @Someprogrammerdude , btw I don't really use printf and scanf so using std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); works fine for me!

Comment: @Chiranjeev Just as long as you remember that those are bad habits (including [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). And unfortunately habits (good and bad) tend to stick.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [user-defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal). The [`s` suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator""s) turns it into a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

For example, lets say you have

```
auto s = ""s;
```

Then it's equivalent to

```
auto s = std::string();
```

Or just

```
std::string s;
```

In other words, it creates an empty `std::string`.

---

In combination with the [lambda capture](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) it defines the variable `s` as an empty `std::string` object, and captures it for use inside the [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: @ThomasSablik From the [user-defined literal reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal): "All 
*ud-suffixes* introduced by a program must begin with the underscore character `_`. **The standard library *ud-suffixes* do not begin with underscores.**" (emphasis mine)